# Showing that three rings are isomorphic

Tags: ring-theory, group-rings, ring-isomorphism

Let $C_3 = \langle a | a^3 = e \rangle$ and let $R=(\mathbb{Z}/2)[C_3]$ be the group ring of $C_3$ with $\mathbb{Z}/2$ coefficients. 
Let $S = (\mathbb{Z}/2)[y]/(y^3-[1])$ and let $T = \mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x^3-1)$. Prove that $S,T$, and $R$ are pairwise isomorphic rings.

Comment: Can you think of an isomorphism between $R$ and $S$ at least? If this is not possible, then try to write down the elements of $R$ and $S$ explicitly, and find a pattern  that you can exploit. A similar sort of procedure should be adopted if you cannot figure out anything between $S$ and $T$.

Comment: For $S$ and $T,$ try to construct a surjective homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ to $S$ with kernel $(2, x^3-1).$ Again, the same for $R$ and $S.$

Comment: From $(\mathbb{Z}/2)[x]$ to R it seems that an isomorphism would be the evaluation homomorphism at $a$. Would that work?